# How do I set the mode-line "box" property to be the same color as the "background" (running emacs daemon)

Tags: mode-line

I'm trying to set the "box" property (the border) of my mode-line to match whatever the background color is. Here's what I've tried to do:

```
(add-to-list 'after-make-frame-functions
    (lambda (_)
     (let ((x (face-background 'mode-line)))
       (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
                       :box `(:line-width 10 :color ,x)))))
```

But this results in `emacsclient` not opening, yet `emacs` and `emacs -Q` will. Nothing shows up in `*Messages*`.

If I start with `emacs -Q`, the box doesn't show up. I want to do this because I want to style my modeline with some padding around it. The color of the `:box` ends up being whatever the foreground is by default, and instead, I want it to match the background. This is so that even if I reload a theme, it will still keep the same `:box`. If I load up emacsclient without this code added to my init file, then eval the set-face-attribute above, it will work as desired.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do that? Why not just remove the :box attribute (or don't add it in the first place)? I have a feeling that some info is missing from your question. Do you see a :box attribute if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find where you're adding it.

Comment: @Drew No :box attrib. if starting with `emacs -Q` (same behaviour with `emacs`) I want to do this because I want to style my modeline with some padding around it. The color of the box is whatever the foreground is by default, and I want it to match the background. This is so even if I reload a theme, it will still keep the same padding.

If I load up `emacsclient` without this code added to my init file, then eval the `set-face-attribute` above, it will work as expected.

Comment: I see. Please add that info to the question, for clarity. Questions need to stand on their own - comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: @Drew done, added to question